# Match character In Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am a beginner programmer and i can't get this. Need to call a .txt file containing data and match character (*) and return the value.

the .txt file contains below data :

```
Zone : Server1
       00:88:41:oc*
       12:11:ee:41
Zone : Server2
       1e:41:eq:re
       oc:41:31:26
Zone : Server3
       00:88:41:ae*
       1e:19:ee:46
```

So as there is a (*) at the end it should return the "Zone" name ..expected result is :

```
Server1
Server3
```

What i am trying :

```
import re
s = open('./myfile.txt','r').read()
fp = open('./output.txt', 'w')
for zone in s.split("zone"):
    m = re.search(r"\w+\*", zone)
    if m:
        fp.write(zone.splitlines()[0].strip(" :"))
```

Comment: SO expects you to show your attempts.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist : Server2 does not have (*) at the end in its following lines ..so the output should nt give Server2

Comment: what if i need the return value as server 2 ( no " * " )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """Zone : Server1
       00:88:41:oc*
       12:11:ee:41
Zone : Server2
       1e:41:eq:re
       oc:41:31:26
Zone : Server3
       00:88:41:ae*
       1e:19:ee:46"""

for zone in s.split("Zone"):             #Separate Each zone
    m = re.search(r"\w+\*", zone)        #Check for *
    if m:
        print(zone.splitlines()[0].strip(" :"))   #Get first line.
```

**Output:**

```
Server1
Server3
```

Comment: if i have to take data from .txt file then ?

Comment: i am trying to keep "s" in "myfile.txt" and get the output in "output.txt"...Can i get the zone name in one column ? i am getting in a row..i have updated in question what i am trying ..

Comment: what if i need the return value as server 2 ( no " * " )  ?